# How To access facebook login and fetch user information using OpenId authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth

I have a problem in login with facebook using OpenId authentication provider, when I enter email id and password on login form it simply shows me message that "The website cannot display the page" and further also mention that "The parameter app_id is required".

Comment: I think you should create a one sample application for that

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Facebook uses OAUTH to access it's APIs.

Sorry mate, but you are going to have to read up the documentation on the Facebook API, OAUTH and work on this a bit more.